# How can I render a variable globaly in play framework

Tags: playframework

I want to use a List of Objects globally for all views so that I can use that in all views to create navigation with the `#list` tag. I thought I could do that  on application startup programatically, but I do not really see how I can do that.

Any ideas.

BR, Rene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to create navigation, you best bet is to create a [tag](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/templates#tags) that gets the objects form a specific controller and reuse that tag around your application.

An alternative is to use a @Before method in a controller to set the list via renderArgs.put("myList", ) and then you'll be able to access the list as ${myList}, but in your case that would be overkill and make maintenance harder that required.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am using a FastTag to access the model to get the wanted list. Really powerfull mechanism.